# Group by or partition by multiple columns and a pair of values of a single column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table in a postgres table that represents the movement of entries on and off a list:

| Entry | Event | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dog | Add | 2021-01-01 |
| Dog | Remove | 2021-01-02 |
| Dog | Add | 2021-01-31 |
| Dog | Remove | 2021-02-01 |
| Cat | Add | 2021-01-31 |
| Cat | Remove | 2021-02-01 |

I'd like to group the rows by the "Entry" column and "Event" column by "add"/"remove" value pairs to have a row that would denote the time that the record was on the list.

Output table:

| Entry | Added | Removed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dog | 2021-01-01 | 2021-01-02 |
| Dog | 2021-01-31 | 2021-02-01 |
| Cat | 2021-01-31 | 2021-02-01 |

That way you could query the results of the table to see if "dog" was on the list at a given time easily with the following:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Entry = 'Dog' AND '2021-01-01' between Added AND Removed
```

Looking for a little SQL help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a subquery to get the removal date for an `Add` entry:

```
select e.entry, e.tmsp, (select min(e1.tmsp) from events e1 
     where e1.entry = e.entry and e1.event = 'Remove' and e1.tmsp > e.tmsp) 
from events e where e.event = 'Add'
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=0a586668d7976c91d33a1779b8233098).